# Group and Count Oldest Registries

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have something like this in my database:

```
Id   CustomerId  ExecutionDate            OfficeId
-------------------------------------------------
1      1         2016-11-17 00:00:00.000  1
2    133         2016-12-23 00:00:00.000  3
3      1         2017-01-27 00:00:00.000  1
4    230         2023-04-11 00:00:00.000  2
5    133         2023-04-12 00:00:00.000  3
6      1         2024-04-13 00:00:00.000  1
7      1         2023-04-17 00:00:00.000  1
```

I need to count how many customers have One Distinct Execution in each year.

It is the way I can know when that customer was first processed, so I can measure growing by year.

The result must be something like this:

```
Year    NewCustomers
--------------------------
2016    2
2017    1
2023    3
2024    1
```

Also, If I need to count how many Offices by year, it would be just do the same logic, just changing the column name?

```
Year    NewOffices
--------------------------
2016    2
2023    1
```

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    YEAR(MIN(ExecutionDate)) 
FROM
    ExecRegistry
GROUP BY
    CustomerId, YEAR(MIN(ExecutionDate))
ORDER BY
    YEAR(MIN(ExecutionDate));
```

Comment: FYI a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *distinct* but as part of the count aggregate, such as:

```
select [Year], Count(distinct CustomerId) NewOffices
from ExecRegistry
cross apply(values(Year(ExecutionDate)))y([Year])
group by [Year]
order by [Year];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ExecutionDate) AS Year,
    COUNT(CustomerId) AS NewCustomers
FROM
    ExecRegistry
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ExecutionDate)
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) = 1;
```

- It extracts the year from the ExecutionDate using the EXTRACT
  function then groups the records by the extracted year.
- It uses the COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) to count the number of
  distinct customers in each year.
- The HAVING clause filters the result to include only those years
  where the count of distinct customers is equal to 1, indicating that
  there is only one customer with a distinct execution in that year.